# Make SharePoint accessible from the Internet via a specific port?

Tags: 2007, alternate-access-mapping, internet-sites

I am a junior sharepoint admin at some government public bureau.

Recently i've been trying to figure out how to make an internal sharepoint web app (MOSS 2007) on a specific port (e.g: http://web:20000) accessible from the internet, still using the default port (e.g: http://web.example.com:20000/)...or any other port than port 80 ?

Besides extending the web app to same port, and then configure this in AAM, what else is missing?

Is there any additional setting that i have to configure in IIS, Active Directory, or the local DNS server?

Answer (score 1):

there are several ways to achieve this. Most important for public sites with SharePoint is the same like with others: hardening! So before we can start planning your publishing let's collect some further information:

Which Authentication do you plan for external users?
Which Firewall/Proxy product do you use in front of SharePoint (ISA, TMG, UAG, other)?

Comment: Thankyou sir for your response, 

I am still using Windows Authentication (NTLM), i read several books about sharepoint, and the authors mentioned about Kerberos, but they refer to some MSDN link (which i still trying to understand)...is it Kerberos that hard ?

I have ISA Server 2006, and my farm were: 

2WFE + 1 SQL + 1 Active Directory + 1 email server (Exchange 2007 SP2)

All running windows server 2003 R2 with latest service pack, sorry if my explanation not clear enough...


Regards,